# Extra space added when selecting div content

Tags: css, internet-explorer, razor

I am working on a very annoying bug. The problem is that it happens only in Internet Explorer (I use IE 10). When I try to select the content of a div tag an extra space is added at the end of my selection. Still, Internet explorer has this option for switching the compatibility mode and if I use the extra space will not be there any more. Is there any .css or .cshtml trick I could use for my MVC4 view?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="display"> "text" </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.display {
    margin: 0.1em 0 0 0;
    border: 0.1em 0 0;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by `selecting` you mean when you highlight and copy manually from within the browser

The html you provided, the actual content of the div is `[space]text[space]`

Chrome appears to be clever and excludes the trailing space. IE, on the other hand, copies the value verbatim

Try removing the spaces surrounding the text - if you require them for your styling, try adding some padding instead

```
.display {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0.1em 0 0 0;
    border: 0.1em 0 0;
    width: 320px;
}
```